# Check current fragment in viewpager that was attached in Activity's onAttachFragment()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a callback method I need to call once a fragment in my ViewPager is attached to my activity. In order to do this I'm overriding `onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment)` in the activity.

But I have 3 fragments in the ViewPager, so how can I check the fragment parameter in `OnAttachFragment()` to make sure it's the specific fragment I need?

If I am going about this wrong, I would like to know how to accomplish this the right way.

Comment: Can't you get it via the adapter that was set to the viewpager ?

Comment: I tried that but my app was crashing because the fragment was still null. I got it working though!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Instead of calling `OnAttachFragment()` in the activity, I'm calling the callback method in `onActivityCreated()` in the fragment where it needs to be called.